# SwiftUI Multiple Timer Management

Tags: swift, for-loop, swiftui, timer

I'm making the app needs to control several timer at once, and now facing 2 problems.
1: N timers keep running N times faster than expected.
2: Stop button not working for each timer.

2nd problem is the core problem that I'm running into the real project, and would like to understand how to manage the multiple timer instances when they are generated with loop structure.

I pasted the test code, and this code does not use TimelineView for a reason, understanding how the Timer works.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var timerData = TimerDataViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
                CurrentDateView(timerData: timerData)
                Button(action:{
                    timerData.stop()
                }, label:{
                    Text("STOP THIS TIMER")
                })
            }
        }
        
    }
}
struct CurrentDateView: View {
    @State private var currentDate = Date()
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @ObservedObject var timerData: TimerDataViewModel
    var body: some View {

        Text("\(Int(timerData.hoursElapsed), specifier: "%02d"):\(Int(timerData.minutesElapsed), specifier: "%02d"):\(Int(timerData.secondsElapsed), specifier: "%02d")")
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .onAppear(){
                timerData.start()
            }
    }
}

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class TimerDataViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var timer = Timer()
    @Published var startTime : Double = 0.0
    @Published var secondsOriginal = 0.0
    @Published var secondsElapsed = 0.0
    @Published var secondsElapsed_ = 0.0
    @Published var minutesElapsed = 0.0
    @Published var hoursElapsed = 0.0
    
    enum stopWatchMode {
        case running
        case stopped
        case paused
    }
    
    init(){
//        start()
        print("initialized")
    }

    
    func start(){
            self.secondsOriginal = self.startTime
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true){ timer in
                self.secondsOriginal += 1
                self.secondsElapsed_ = Double(Int(self.secondsOriginal))
                self.secondsElapsed = Double(Int(self.secondsOriginal)%60)
                self.minutesElapsed = Double(Int(self.secondsOriginal)/60 % 60)
                self.hoursElapsed = Double(Int(self.secondsOriginal)/3600 % 24)
            }
    }
    
    func stop(){
        self.timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI Timer keep resetting when updating the ObservedObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69375932/swiftui-timer-keep-resetting-when-updating-the-observedobjects)

Comment: What your code is actually doing is creating 10 views that are attached to the same timer.  You create one instance of `TimerDataViewModel` and it creates one timer.  All the views then share that timer.  Each `CurrentDateView` is also creating a timer, but no `Subscriber`s are listening to it.